# What happens when more than one person with the same initials joins the Men in Black?

Tags: names, men-in-black, men-in-black-3, men-in-black-2

As seen in the film, *Men in Black* (1997), when a person becomes a part of the Men in Black organization their name is erased and they are given a code name which is the first letter of their birth name. E.g. In the 1997 film, James Darrell Edwards III becomes "Agent J" (or "Agent Jay", depending on who you ask) and in *Men in Black II* (2002) "Agent K" (or "Agent Kay") is revealed to have once been Kevin Brown.

So, what happens if more than one person with the initial "J" or any other letter joined the MiB (Men in Black)? Additionally, what happens when there are more than 26 MiB agents working at one time?

Unless I somehow miscounted, I believe during all three of the *Men in Black* films (1997-2012) which I have seen, it can be seen that there are **more** than 26 operatives employed at any one time.

Also, during *Men in Black 3* (2012), there is a scene where a row of memorial busts are shown with the codenames of deceased agents displayed. What happens if more than one agent named John, Jack, or James is killed in action?

Relevant videos:

- James Darrell Edwards becomes "Agent J":
- Footage featuring the aforementioned "memorial busts":

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MIB Agent names appear to be assigned based on the basis of first name. **Where two agents share a first initial, a second initial or a descriptor can be used to disambiguate.**

In MiB3 we meet J's new partner ["*Double-A*"](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/Agent_AA)  (formerly Andrew Arnett). This presumably leaves the way open for there to also be an [*"Agent A"*](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/Agent_A)

[image]

In MiBI, we meet ["*High T*"](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/High_T), formerly Agent T. This presumably leaves the way open for there to be a new [Agent T](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/Agent_T).

[image]